# Kendo TreeView - load the items with infinite scroll

Tags: kendo-ui, infinite-scroll, kendo-treeview

When I have a big tree that I build with kendo tree view, the time until we can see the tree is very long, and sometimes it hangs the browser.
I think it's because I am loading all the tree items of the tree..
I tried using loadOnDemand: true and all folders to load them collapsed, and it solve the problem, but I don't want to collapse the folders, I want to load it expanded.

Is there a way to do it?
Maybe an infinite scroll that what we see in the current position in the scroll, is what we see in the DOM, and not to see the all tree in the DOM.

Thanks

Comment: Had this problem once, never found a solution tho.